# Как реализовать кнопки регулирования кол-ва товара в корзине в DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

В процессе реализации отображения корзины магазина понадобился функционал регулирования количества товара в самой корзине кнопками "+" и "-". Выглядеть это дожно как-то так (прошу прощение за качество):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как такое реализовать в DataGrid, или, возможно, есть способ получше?

Comment: Если вы делаете все по уму, у вас используется XAML, привязки, и все в этом духе, то такое сделать элементарно, достаточно создать еще одну колонку, в которой будет 2 кнопки, привязанные к своим командами, и привязанная циферка к свойству, все. А как у вас там на самом деле, ну я лично не знаю. Если делать прям совсем по уму, то делаем отдельный контрол, который будет содержать эти 2 кнопки и циферку, а в колонке уже используем его, где просто привязываем саму циферку.

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса не очень ясно, как у вас устроена привязка данных к DataGrid. Но по-хорошему, вам следует создать список из элементов типа ProductCartModel. А в модели расписать все свойства объекта: название, цена, количество, картинка и прочее:

```
class ProductCartModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

А затем привязать отображение цены к числу, выводимому на экран, а по нажатию кнопок изменять цену.

Возможно, [эти видео](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-p05fYs48r-HOAA4_5qZfS0rTIka3fgc) будут вам полезны.